# How do I access the return collection using monk, mongodb, and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This returns an object but I can't determine how to access the json object values.

Error:

Express
500 TypeError: /home/mark/projects/soundone/views/event/category.jade:11
 9| p Enter... #{qtest.myTest} 
 10| 
 > 11| - var events = myevent.myEvents.docs.EventName
 12| 
 13| p some data events.docs 
 14| p more 
Cannot read property 'EventName' of undefined

Cannot read property 'EventName' of undefined

---

```
// Events data
// public/javascripts/events.js


var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/soundevents');
var eventcollection = db.get('event');


var myEvents = eventcollection.find({}, {limit:1}, function(err, docs){});
var eventName = myEvents.docs.EventName;


module.exports.myEvents = myEvents;
module.exports.eventName = eventName;
```

---

```
 /*
  * THis has functionality for categories.
  *  ../routes/category.js
  *
 */

 var mytest = require('../public/javascripts/test');
 var myevent = require('../public/javascripts/events');


exports.newcategory = function(req, res) {
   res.render('event/category', {title: 'New Category',
   qtest: mytest, myevent: myevent, eventone: eventName});
};
```

---

```
extends ../layout
// views/event/category.jade

block content
  h2 #{title}
  div


    p Enter... #{qtest.myTest}  #{eventone}

    - var events = myevent.myEvents.docs.EventName

    p some data events.docs
```

---

```
> db.event.find().pretty()
{
    "EventName" : "12hrs of 360",
    "UpdateTime" : 1391897660023,
    "EventDescription" : "A real cool 12hour race, bring your lights",
    "EventLocation" : "360 park",
    "EventStartDate" : "05/31/2014",
    "eventStartTime" : "1800",
    "_id" : ObjectId("52f6ac3c99c9066a6f000001")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you are using find and a limit of one..better use findOne..Something like

```
var myEvents = eventcollection.findOne(query, [fields, [options]], callback);
```

If there is no criteria that you are looking to match, you can the query blank too.

Secondly, find would return a cursor/a list of matching results. If you need to access the properties of the docs using find, one of the ways can be

```
var eventName = myEvents[0].EventName;
```

or you could go by the normal, for/foreach loop and then get the values.

Comment: Thanks - I had a limit of 20, but changed to to 1 for a test